# Mininet set IP of host from a python file

Tags: python, mininet

I would like to run a python file on the default Mininet host h1, which alters the IP address of h1 and sends data from h1 to other targets.
How can I do this?
On the Mininet command line, changing the IP address is done as follows:
`py h1.setIP('Ipaddress')`.

What I would like is:

```
h1 run_python_file new_ip
```

which would change the IP address of h1 to new_ip, create a socket, and send random data to a destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a script at host h1 by first navigating to the directory of the script and then running `h1 python3 nameOfScript.py`.
You can think of `h1` as a Linux machine, so running a Python script needs to be done via the `python3` command. Here is another example:

```
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> h1 python3 hello.py
hello world
mininet>
```

I created a hello.py script and started Mininet from the same directory by running `sudo mn`, then I can called the script.
You can pass the `new_ip` argument to the script as per Python's docs.